# MS Access - auto complete

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am an Access newbie (using 2013), so my apologies if this a simple one... I've tried to figure this out from google and YouTube videos, but I'm finding myself more and more confused.

I have a form that I'm using to enter and view project management data. The form contains data from 2 related tables: 1) TblClients, and 2) TblProjects (each client can have multiple projects). Clients can be "internal" or "external"... and this is assigned through a field in TblClients called "ExternalClient?" through a Yes/No combo box.

In TblProjects, I have several fields (e.g. "QuoteGenerated?", "ServiceContractExecuted?") that are used to track project specific administrative tasks that are ONLY necessary for External clients. These fields are combo boxes that contain Yes, No, or N/A internal. Each of these fields in the form currently defaults to "No".

The form is working - but I have to manually assign each entry for "QuoteGenerated" etc.

What I'm struggling with is the following: when I add a new record to the data entry form and select the client for the project (through a clientID combo box), I'd like each of the fields for "QuoteGenerated?", "ServiceContractExecuted?" etc to be "N/A internal" if the client is internal. These entries would need to be stored in TblProjects. I'd also like to retain the combo box so that once each task is complete, I could set it to "yes" and store this value.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions... please let me know if I can provide more information.

Cheers!

EDIT: @M.Nabavi Thanks for your reply. Something is not working for me though... I have added the following code:

```
 Private Sub ExternalClient__AfterUpdate()
    If ExternalClient.Value = "Yes" Then
        txtAdminQuote = "No"
        txtAdminToLegal = "No"
        txtAdminToClient = "No"
        txtAdminFromClient = "No"
        txtAdminExecuted = "No"
    Else
        txtAdminQuote = "N/A (internal client)"
        txtAdminToLegal = "N/A (internal client)"
        txtAdminToClient = "N/A (internal client)"
        txtAdminFromClient = "N/A (internal client)"
        txtAdminExecuted = "N/A (internal client)"
    End If
```

where ExternalClient is the name (does it need to be the control source?) of the combo box containing the external client Y/N, and AdminQuote, AdminToLegal etc are the names of the fields I want to populate.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Handle This Problem by VBA

1- Open Your Form In Design Mode And Right Click On Your Combo Box

2- Click On Properties Then Select Event Tab

3- On After Update Event Add code similar to the following code:

`Private Sub cmbExternalLink_AfterUpdate()
    If cmbExternalLink.Value = "Yes" Then
        txtQuoteGenerated = "Yes Value"
        txtServiceContractExecuted = "Yes Value"
    Else
        txtQuoteGenerated = "No Value"
        txtServiceContractExecuted = "No Value"
    End If
End Sub`

Enjoy It